# Dynamic zsh autocomplete for custom commands

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm trying to write completion functions for some custom functions I wrote, but seem to be really struggling with even the most basic ones.

An example function is:

```
function eb_instances() {
    if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage eb_instances <aws profile name> <environment name>"
        echo "e.g.:"
        echo " eb_instances production kraken-prod-api"
        return 1
    fi

    aws ec2 describe-instances --filters  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"   "Name=tag:Name,Values=$2" --profile=$1 --output=json | jq -r ".Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress"
}
```

This has two positional arguments, `<aws profile name>` and `<environment name>`

I want the completion options for `<aws profile name>` to be dynamically available by running 
`sed -n -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\]/\1/p' ~/.aws/credentials | tr \\n ' '`, and the completions for `<environment name>` to be dynamically available by running another function I have called `eb_names`.

I'm finding the documentation quite sparse and difficult to follow. I've also seen the zsh-completions repo for similar commands but can't seem to find something similar to what I need.

Any help getting started would be much appreciated!

**Update**

Based on [@cuonglm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240192/38906), I used:

```
#compdef ebinstances

_ebinstances() {
  local state

  _arguments \
    '1: :->aws_profile'\
    '*: :->eb_name'

  case $state in
    (aws_profile) _arguments '1:profiles:($(sed -n -E "s/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\]/\1/p" ~/.aws/credentials | tr \\n " "))' ;;
              (*) compadd "$@" foo bar
  esac
}

_ebinstances "$@"
```

What I forgot to mention in the original question was, that I also wanted the completion of the second argument be dependent on the first one (both of which are dynamic based executing some code), for example:

```
$ eb_instances <cursor>TAB
cuonglm  test
```

gets the completions I want. Once I select say the first one, and try to auto complete:

```
$ eb_instances cuonglm <cursor>TAB
```

I want to generate the completion options by executing `eb_names cuonglm`, and if possible, also, drilldown on the completions for example if the correct candidate was `foo-bar`,

```
$ eb_instances cuonglm foo<cursor>TAB
```

I want to generate the completion options by executing `eb_names cuonglm foo`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

At first, the [zsh Completion System](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) seems to be very complex and difficult to grasp. Let's try an example.

The first thing you need to know is that the `zsh` completion system will load completion functions from `$fpath`. Make sure your completions directory appear in:

```
print -rl -- $fpath
```

(If you're using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), `.oh-my-zsh/completions` is in `$fpath`.  You can just create it and put your completion functions there.)

Now, you must create a completion file for your function.  Its name must start with underscore (`_`) plus your function name. In your case, its name would be `_eb_instances`.

Add these lines to the `_eb_instances` file:

```
#compdef eb_instances

_eb_instances() {
  local state

  _arguments \
    '1: :->aws_profile'\
    '*: :->eb_name'

  case $state in
    (aws_profile) _arguments '1:profiles:(cuonglm test)' ;;
              (*) compadd "$@" prod staging dev
  esac
}

_eb_instances "$@"
```

You are done. Save the file and start a new session to test completion. You will see something like this:

```
$ eb_instances <cursor>TAB
cuonglm  test

$ eb_instances cuonglm <cursor>TAB
dev      prod     staging
```

You can read the zsh completion system documentation about the `_arguments` function and `state` variable. Also, you will need to change `(cuonglm test)` to your `sed` command and change `prod staging dev` to your `eb_names` function.

If you want to generate the 2nd argument based on what 1st argument was passed, you can use the `$words[2]` variable:

```
case $state in
  (aws_profile) _arguments '1:profiles:(cuonglm test)' ;;
            (*) compadd "$@" $(echo $words[2]) ;;
esac
```

Replace `echo` with your real function.  In your case, it's `$(eb_names $words[2])`.

If you still have trouble with this, just define `_eb_instances` and `eb_instances` in your `.zshrc` then call completion as:

```
compdef _eb_instances eb_instances
```

---

You need to initialize the completion system with:

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
```

(If you used `oh-my-zsh`, it have been loaded)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. The problem though that I can't seem to find a well documented way to do, is what if my completion options are dynamic, or come from other functions/scripts, ie, in your example, what if I wanted `cuonglm test` to come from `sed -n -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\]/\1/p' ~/.aws/credentials | tr \\n ' '`

Comment: @zsquare: Just replace `(cuonglm test)` with `($(sed -n -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\]/\1/p' ~/.aws/credentials | tr \\n ' '))`, change `compadd "$@" prod staging dev` to `compadd "$@" $(eb_names)`.

Comment: this may be stretching it a little, but, I forgot to mention, that need to pass `eb_names` the first argument, ie, `production` or `staging`, how do I do that? Thanks a lot, I've gotten quite a few things sorted with this.

Comment: I mean't I wanted to use the first argument in to pass to eb_names. I tried referencing `$1` or `$2`, but no dice.

Comment: I updated the question. If you think it is worth a separate question, let me know, I will move it.

Comment: @zsquare: See my updated!

Comment: You're a wizard, Harry.

Comment: For some reason my script is not recognized, any idea why? I've placed my script in `/Users/myuser/.oh-my-zsh/completions`, prefixed the file with underscore but zsh won't suggest it (reloaded terminal, made sure path is printed in `print -rl -- $fpath`)