# How do I add a command to zsh history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

I'd like to use a zsh script to append a command to the command history so that it appears when I hit the up arrow. I've been appending a line to ${HISTFILE}, and it shows up there as the last line, but the up arrow action appears to ignore it.

I see that zsh maintains a session history in parallel to the history file, but I haven't yet seen a way to add to it, or to otherwise accomplish what I'm setting out to do. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to add to the history or the command completion directory?
I suspect the later, in which case this might help:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239528/dynamic-zsh-autocomplete-for-custom-commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `print -s` or `print -S` for this:

> `-s`
>
> Place the results in the history list instead of on the standard output. Each argument to the print command is treated as a single word in the history, regardless of its content.
>
> `-S`
>
> Place the results in the history list instead of on the standard output. In this case only a single argument is allowed; it will be split into words as if it were a full shell command line. The effect is similar to reading the line from a history file with the `HIST_LEX_WORDS` option active.

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print